# changing data in R cbind

Tags: r

**i have data that it look like this**

[image]

**i wanna change it to look like that with month on the top and year at the left ,i have tried with cbind  but no way**

[image]

Comment: Search for "reshape long to wide" to give you some ideas. This is a very common question. Also, in the future it's better to post a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (images of data aren't helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution : rs=reshape(out, idvar = "year_actual", timevar = "month_actual", direction = "wide")